# v2.8 cycles - weird color change in Fire Simulation when over background

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine

When I render a frame where the fire goes beyond the plane and over the background the color goes brighter and unsaturated. This happens only in the final render, not in the viewport render. (pic) Tell me if you need any other information about the material and object settings. [image: final render]

[image: Settings]

[image: export settings]

This color problem is what I am talking about: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xFi1.jpg

Comment: With what program did you open the image?

Comment: I have the background as transparent. In the render view of blender and in Photoshop when added a black background its very noticeable.

Comment: You need to describe what you are seeing better. Provide an arrow to where you are talking about in the image, and where it “seems correct” with another image. Sounds like rudimentary compositing and the nature of emissive yet unoccluding fire / flames, but will wait until you provide more information.

Comment: Oh sry. I thought it was clear enough. I was talking about this. https://imgur.com/a/hY1Y5oC

Comment: That’s still not enough information. Show what you think is wrong, and how you are achieving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a problem or a bug as you may think - the smoke is translucent/transparent so the light passes through it and you see what is on the other side. In this case - a plane that appears to be gray. Hence the change in color.
I guess you could increase the smoke density so the light wouldn't pass through it.

Comment: oh thanks, thats reasonable.